# Gently close the door - one word

Tags: word-request

There's *"slam the door"* and *"shut the door"* for non-gentle actions applied towards a door but are there any gentle one-word actions?

I tried to search for the opposite (antonym) of "slam" and "close" but that's not what I was looking for. I have no idea how i should search then.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99197/discussion-on-question-by-sovereignsun-gently-close-the-door-one-word).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thesaurus can give some answers and one word alternatives (synonyms) for *close* in the context of closing an object would be

> bang, bar, block, bolt, button, caulk, choke, clap, clench, clog,
>   confine, congest, cork, dam, exclude, fasten, fill, lock, occlude,
>   plug, retard, screen, secure, shut, shutter, slam, stopper, and stuff

Antonyms are opposite to synonyms and as you will have found, antonyms in this context would be referring to opening an object.

Now we need to narrow the synonyms down for context when referring to closing a door.  These would be

> bang, secure, shut, and slam

Now as a native speaker, I would like to point out that, the use of *secure* can be used in this context, however it would more often refer to the locking of the door after it is closed.

I would understand "close the door" or "shut the door" to be generally in a reasonably quiet manner although closing and shutting can be done in a loud manner.  If using *close* or *shut* you can always use the adverbs *quietly* or *loudly* to avoid confusion.

> Please close the door quietly

If you use the words *bang* or *slam* they are definitely referring to a loud closing of the door.

Comment: Yes, i know that I can say **close quietly** but i would really want to keep the same pattern and place a word instead if *slam* or *shut*.

Comment: The only alternative words for *close* in this context are **bang, secure, shut, and slam**.  So for quiet closing of the door, as indicated in the answer you only have the option of "close the door" or "shut the door".